# Tflearn timeseries input for an RNN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

I've got some short code that attempts to fit a function. But I am worried about how to feed the data to a tflearn rnn.

The X input is a [45,1,8] (45 samples, 4 timesteps, and 8 features] array. Therefore, the Y input should be a [45,1,8] array since the goal is to minimize the difference element-wise.

However it throws the following error when this is attempted

```
Cannot feed value of shape (45, 1, 8) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 8)'
```

I can't seem to figure out my error. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: someone seems to have solved a similar problem, but I can't understand the answer
[tensorflow/tflearn input shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519138/tensorflow-tflearn-input-shape)

Full Code

```
def mod(rnn_output,state):
    Tau = tfl.variable(name='GRN', shape=[8],
                         initializer='uniform_scaling',
                         regularizer='L2')
    Timestep = tf.constant(6.0,shape=[8])
    one = tf.div(Timestep,Tau)
    two = rnn_output
    three = tf.mul(tf.sub(tf.ones(shape=[num_genes]),one),state)
    four = tf.mul(one,two)
    five = tf.add(four,three)
    return(five)
net = tfl.input_data(shape=[None,4,8])
out, state = tfl.layers.recurrent.simple_rnn(net,8,return_state=True
                                            ,name='RNN')
net = tfl.layers.core.custom_layer(out,mod,state=state)
net = tfl.layers.estimator.regression(net)
# Define model
model = tfl.DNN(net)
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=10, batch_size=45, show_metric=True)
```